# Get path of current file in include file php

Tags: php

This is my **header.php** stored in **include** folder

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="index.php">My Account</a></li>
  <li class="somefile.php">Admin Panel</li>
  <li><a href="users.php">Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

**NOTE**: i have to include header.php in both folder

1. Main Root Folder
2. RootFolder/MasterFolder

Now when i am calling file from **Root directory** it works fines 
but when i am include this file in Other folder and call index(My account) so it call like this

```
mysite/master/index.php
```

but i wants when i am calling include file from master named folder

```
mysite/index.php
```

My File Structure is like this

[image: My File Structure]

in master also have files. and my header.php is in **includes** Folder

Comment: how to get absolute path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**URLs and paths are different.**

When you're including your html header in php you should require it using the [document root](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) of the server. This way, no matter which system you're on, you can still access it.

If `telecaller` is your web [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory) directory, then you should have the code:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/header.php');
```

Paths can then be [relative URLs](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html) in the HTML inside of that header.

```
<a href='/index.php'>Telecaller Index File</a>
<a href='/master/index.php'>Master Index File</a>
<script src='/ajax/something.js'></script>
<a href='/login.php'>login page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="../index.php">My Account</a></li>
  <li class="../somefile.php">Admin Panel</li>
  <li><a href="../users.php">Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can give a relative path like this, or give absolute path
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: now its not working in root file. if i click on My account it redirect me out of application

Comment: can you provide your file structure? and how you want to arrange it?

Comment: @AkshayDNG check now?

Comment: Dear Lakindu Its working fine only when i am in master folder. outside master folder i also include this file so it will redirect me out of application if i select this outside master folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
define('ROOTPATH', __DIR__);
//define root path
// and make link of file from the root path 
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="<?php echo ROOTPATH.'index.php'; ?>">My Account</a></li>
  <li class="<?php echo ROOTPATH.'somefile.php'; ?>">Admin Panel</li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo ROOTPATH.'users.php'; ?>">Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: NOt working from Mater folder. it shows path like `folder/master/include/index.php` which does not exist.

Comment: @AkshayDNG does your index.php in root path if not then include `/master/include/` in the link of index.php . and pls read about url and href how it works.